# Money type out of interval

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I have an mssql table with money type column.
I'm trying to update that and getting the error "1000000,000 is out of interval".
Here is the code:

```
TradingResult trading = new TradingResult() { Id = 1 };
trading.Price = 1000000.00M;
context.Trading.Attach(trading);
context.Entry(trading).Property(o => o.Price).IsModified = true;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Works fine when price has one less zero or try to update via query analyzer.
I think the problem is the precision param, how can i change this ?